# DBIC generates an "Invalid precision" error for a primary key

Tags: perl, dbix-class

The table stores file names. The primary key is an auto-incrementing integer. A search using the result set works. And calling the *delete* method generates the following error message:

```
DBIx::Class::Relationship::CascadeActions::delete(): DBI Exception: 
DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid 
precision value (SQL-HY104) [for Statement "DELETE FROM tblComplaintAttachment 
WHERE ( ID = ? )" with ParamValues: 1='8.4.9.3.0.'] at Dups.pl line 17
```

ID is the primary key. If I print ID, it shows **84930** - without the periods. Any ideas why *delete* generates the error?

The database is SQL Server 2000. I am using DBIx::Class with Strawberry Perl under Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

From [DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::ODBC](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08121_01/lib/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI/ODBC/ACCESS.pm). I'm not sure that's exactly the problem, but it may serve as a starting point to you.

> KNOWN ACCESS PROBLEMS ^
>
> Invalid precision value
>
> This error message is received when trying to store more than 255
>   characters in a MEMO field. The
>   problem is (to my knowledge) an error
>   in the MS Access ODBC driver. The
>   problem is fixed by setting the
>   data_type of the column to
>   SQL_LONGVARCHAR in add_columns.
>   SQL_LONGVARCHAR is a constant in the
>   DBI module

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This field is an integer - not a Memo. I have the size set as 4. Should I use a different size for integers?

Comment: Are you sure the field is an `int`? My understanding is that in Sql Server, `int` fields don't have the precision property. And isn't '8.4.9.3.0.' a suspicious value for a primary key?